# Creating an Angular2 Project in Eclipse Behind a Proxy

Tags: angularjs, node.js, eclipse, proxy

**How can I successfully setup an Angular2 Project in Eclipse behind a corporate proxy???**

I'm sure this is as simple as following the setup wizard on a home computer, but I've ran into a dozen issues with npm not installing what it needs to because of the proxy here at my job. And I am certainly not the only one.

I have scoured the interwebs for the past 2 days looking for a working solution to this, and have found nothing. So some questions I have are:

- What proxy configs have to be set?
- Any overrides to the npm or angular cli?
- Any specific versions of Node/npm/angular cli I should use?

If anybody out there has had success with this, please share! Thank you!

**Edit**

What I've configured so far

- Set my http and https proxy entries appropriately in Network Connections
- Added `http://registry.npmjs.org` as a proxy bypass

Comment: https://jjasonclark.com/how-to-setup-node-behind-web-proxy/

Comment: I've referenced this article before and I'm sure it could work via command line; is there any way I can declare `npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080` in Eclipse?

Comment: the `npm` used by eclipse is same as global npm. The configuration for npm is defined in `~/.npmrc` making the changes you can use the same in Eclipse. Try restarting eclipse if this doesn't work, might be some cache issue on the ide :)

Comment: It's an interesting topic. Please create an issue at https://github.com/angelozerr/angular2-eclipse/issues/ in order to I study if we could use "General / Networks Configuration"  http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-net-preferences.htm for "npm"

Answer (score 0):

### how to do angular cli install behind corporate proxy

### step: 0:

By default : once installed Node Js without comparny proxy it will set npm registry.
If you want to set global npm regristry follow the step. But out case start from Step:1

npm set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/

Seems it is a certificate expire issue with:

npm registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
in stead run:

### delete proxy:

npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy

Step 1

Open command prompt of your system (run as administrator).

Step 2

In command prompt, type the below-highlighted command and enter,

C:\windows\system32>ping proxy

Step 3

You will find proxy URL of your work environment very similar to the below proxy URL format in the first line,

proxy.[company name].com    or proxy.{extension}.[company name].net

step:4

npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080

Step 5

Once TypeScript is installed successfully, run the below command just to check which TypeScript version is installed,

> tsc –v